# Difference between drawing using Gnuplot and OriginLab

Tags: gnuplot

I have two data files, qebands.agr and ex1_band.dat. When I plot them using OriginLab I got directly this figure:

[image]

On the other hand, someone used Gnuplot with the following script:

```
set xtics nomirr
set x2tics
set xrange [*:*] noextend
set x2range [*:*] noextend
plot 'qebands.agr' w l, 'ex1_band.dat' axes x2y1 w l
```

and get:

[image]

I haven't used Gnuplot before.
Could anyone tell me why the two figures are different? i.e., why the scale the x-axis is different in both figures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on which image is the desired one...

Remove `axes x2y1` in the second part of the gnuplot command and you will get a similar plot as the Origin one.

You are explicitly specifying that `'ex1_band.dat'` is plotted to `axes x2y1` (x2 = top x-axis, y1 = left y-axis).
Per default, gnuplot autoscales both x-axes independently, unless you link them (check `help link`).

Origin is plotting both files relative to `x1y1` axes.